# Evaluate right hand limit $\lim_{x\to 2^+} (x^2 + e^{\frac{1}{2-x}})^{-1}$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to 2^+} \frac{1}{x^2 + e^{\frac{1}{2-x}}}  = \frac{1}{\lim_{x\to 2^+} x^2 + \lim_{h\to 0} e^{\frac{1}{h}}} =\frac{1}{4+\lim_{h\to 0} e^{\frac 1h}}$$

How do I solve further ?

Comment: It's not $\lim_{h \to 0} e^{\frac 1h}$. It is $\lim_{h \to 0^-} e^{\frac 1h}$, so that particular term reduces to zero, giving $\frac 14$.

Comment: Oberve that $h\to 0_-$ if $x\to 2^+$.

Comment: Use $\lim h\to 0^+ \frac{1}{(2+h)^2+e^{-1/h}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a small mistake, it should be
$$L=\frac{1}{4+\lim_{h\to 0} 2^{-1/h}}=1/4.$$
Remember, $h$ is always positive and $$\lim_{x\to 2^+}f(x) \implies \lim_{h \to 0} f(2+h).$$
Similarly, $$\lim_{x \to 2^-}f(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} f(2-h)$$

Answer (score 1):

$x>2$ implies that $h=x-2 <0$ so you have to take limit of $e^{1/h}$ through negative values of $h$. The answer is therefore $\frac 1  {4+0}=\frac 1 4$.

Comment: So it’s basically $e^{-\infty}=0$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

We have that:

$$\frac{1}{2-x} \to -\infty\color{blue}{\left[\frac1{0^-}\right]} \implies e^{\frac{1}{2-x}}\to 0\color{blue}{\left[e^{-\infty}\right]}$$

then

$$x^2 + e^{\frac{1}{2-x}} \to 4+0=4$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to 2^+} (x^2 + e^{\frac{1}{2-x}})^{-1}=\frac14$$